# tense of verbs in the following phrase

Tags: verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Please help me with the correct form (tense) of verbs in the following phrase:

> Some ideas had been previously suggested, but because something else is happening, no idea proved good enough.

The context: the ideas were suggested in the past, but they are some new ideas suggested in the present too. Something else happened, but is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

**Some ideas have been suggested, but because something else is happening, no idea has proved good enough.**

The verb 'have been suggested' is in the present perfect continuous tense, which indicates repeated activities which have happened in the past and are still continuing up until now. Responding to the OP's comment, 'recently' is an entirely subjective term. It can mean 'just a few seconds ago', or 'a couple years ago'. Unless you have a specific date from which the ideas have been suggested from, present perfect continuous is the correct tense.

Comment: It's not a recent action, is something that is happening for years. As a non native speaker I know that present perfect is used for recently completed actions.

Comment: And it's not progressive.  That would be "have been being suggested."

Answer (score 0):

You have three verbs, each governing a particular time from a particular point of view:

> Some ideas (1) *had been suggested* previously<sup>*</sup>, but because something
>   else (2) *is happening*, no idea (3) *proved* good enough.

1. Suggestion time for ideas
2. Happening time for the other event
3. Proving time for the suggested ideas

Unfortunately, the tenses and aspects of the verbs seem to clash with the narrative.  The past perfect (*had been suggested*) governs the time before another past event.  *Previously* doesn't quite work as that past marker because it means anything up to the present.  The past perfect works better in something like

> Some ideas had been suggested before the September deadline passed.

You have two other choices for past events -- the simple past (*were suggested*) and the present perfect (*have been suggested*).  The latter allows for past events from some indeterminate time up to the present, but this is a choice not comfortable with the something else, as we'll see below.  Since it seems the suggestions were made before the something else came on the scene, the better choice is the simple past.

The "something else" unfolds in present progressive (*is happening*), which indicates that the something else is ongoing right now, i.e., it straddles the present having gone on for a bit and expected to continue.  The sense of the sentence seem to put the previous suggestions before this happening, which makes the simple past the appropriate tense for those suggestions.

So when can the something else invalidate the suggestions?  You have three choices with the present, ongoing nature of the something else happening.

A. The suggestions have already been invalidated: use the present perfect which, as mentioned, covers time up to the present.

B. The suggestions are in the process of being invalidated:  use the present progressive to match the happening.

C. The suggestions are about to be invalidated:  use the future to match the expectation.

This gives the following:

> A. Some ideas were previously suggested, but because something else is
>   happening, no idea has proved good enough.
>
> B. Some ideas were previously suggested, but because something else is
>   happening, no idea is proving good enough.
>
> C. Some ideas were previously suggested, but because something else is
>   happening, no idea will prove good enough.

* I moved *previously* to keep the verb elements together.  It doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: Great.  Another DBDV, a plague on this site.